# Inject interface with default implementation to Asp.Net Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection

I have an interface which has on simple method but with defualt implementation like this:

```cs
 public interface ITestService
 {
     string GetName(string name) => $"{name} coming from interface";
 }
```

So this interface doesn't need an implementation class and when I add that in the DI:

```cs
services.AddScoped<ITestService>();
```

I get this error at runtime:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot instantiate implementation type 'ITestService' for service type 'ITestService'.'

Of course it works with adding implementation class and inject to the DI:

```cs
public class TestService : ITestService { }

//....

services.AddScoped<ITestService, TestService>();
```

Is there any way to inject the interface with defualt method implementation?

Comment: Yes, you already showed it to us.

Comment: "So this interface doesn't need an implementation class" yes it does. An interface is not an `object`. A variable requires an instance of an `object` which implements the interface.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman So what's the point of adding default method implementation?

Comment: What you're probably looking for is dynamic code generation. This is something that interception and mocking libraries can do for you, but I'd say they will typically be overkill in your situation where you simply can define a [Null Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) implementation as the one you showed in your question.

Comment: Also all 'object' instances have to implement `.ToString()`, `.Equals()` and `.GetHashCode()`.

Comment: looking for the same answer. This should be supported somethow.

Answer (score 0):

An interface is a lightweight object that is never created and no memory is allocated to it. Therefore, you cannot register it in DIContainer without implementation.